# AudioFormat's frameSize for MP3?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

What is meant by `frameSize` in `AudioFormat` for MP3 format?

Is it compressed length or uncompressed length of 1152 samples?

Comment: MP3 frame size would typically refer to the number of samples in that frame (per channel).  I don't know about the specific class property you are referring to, but I'd imagine that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

FrameSize = 144 * BitRate / SampleRate

source:
http://id3.org/mp3Frame

Here is the website that displays the standards for MP3's. If you want to understand everything about mp3's it is the website to read.

http://id3.org/